# Why do my led bulbs state: not for use in totally enclosed luminaries?

Tags: led, heat

I recently bought some nice inexepensive LED bulbs but I noticed the warning states: (see image below)

> not for use in totally enclosed luminaries

I am guessing that it gets too hot but I find it interesting that it doesn't add that part to the warning text.  I was wondering if it has something to do with it not performing well if it doesn't have air or something.

Also, I wonder if that means I can't use it in overhead lighting like the following: (Again I'm assuming you should not.  It's totally enclosed, but I wasn't sure if it just meant small enclosed luminaries).
[image: small luminary]

[image: sylvania LED bulb]

Comment: Sounds like bad english to me - I would have thought "luminaires" is the word?

Comment: In the lighting industry you'd be surprised how many times "luminaries" sneaks into datasheets, articles, and even ads. Autocorrect FTW!

Comment: Yeah, that's a funny side-point on the luminaries versus luminaires.  :)

Comment: LEDs pump out lots of low grade heat so you should be careful.LED Vs Halogen is like transistor VS valve .

Comment: Thermal design is a big part of functional LED lighting design. IME and IMHO, if you would like a LED ceiling fixture, you should buy one built from the ground up so that good thermal design is included, rather than facing the suboptimal thermal design required to squeeze an LED into an incandescent-shaped-object.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely has to do with heat since the bulb contains electronic components as compared to incandescent bulbs which have none.  Follow the manufacturer's directions or the bulb life will be short.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  I was wondering if they are indicating that it is likely a fire hazard also or if they are just indicating that bulb life will be short. Just curious, I won't use them any any enclosed luminary.

Comment: Because it's (probably) UL rated, risk of fire is probably low. Risk of wasting money on expensive, short-lived LEDs is high though!